# Calculating the probability of a hidden value in a chain, given join probabilities

Tags: probability

I have a system with a large ordered list of "buckets" (B). Each bucket has a known readable label (L). Each bucket also secretly contains exactly one discrete value (V).

I have measured the distribution of the bucket labels and the conditional probabilities that a bucket labeled L contains a particular discrete value V. I also know the joint probability of selecting (V1, V2) when selecting any two adjacent buckets.

My problem: given a sequence of buckets with known labels determine the most likely hidden discrete values.

So far I know...

$$
P(V=v\ \vert\ L=l)\\
P(V_1=v \wedge V_2=v)
$$

However, I get stuck when I consider that the hidden contents of one bucket affects its neighbors which causes a chain reaction. I would expect there to be some "stable" set of values that produces the mostly likely overall state but the process is eluding me.

I looked into Markov Chains but I couldn't figure out how to express the unknown hidden value probability distribution for each bucket. In particular this problem doesn't seem to fit the "memoryless" requirement for Markov Chains.

Update: Currently researching CRFs.